# <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Tags: java, android, permissions, google-play

I'm trying to put an app on google and they reject it in addition to not giving me a concrete answer.
It's an SMS-sending app. I don't keep any user data.
The user fills in 3 fields and is sent to a predefined toll-free number, which sends a reply.

The part of the number and the answer is not up to the app: it is just to facilitate the user's work.

Here is my manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/tres"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/tres"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FieldLocalize"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-4545343114224253~3369918696"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```
private void requerirPermissao() {
    if (!permissaoConcedida()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
    }
}

private boolean permissaoConcedida() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Comment: "it's a sms sending app" - sadly google doesn't really like those. Only instance where this permission is allowed on play store is when you implement a full-blown sms messaging app replacement. Otherwise best you can do is drop the permission and use sms intent so default sms app opens with pre-filled fields.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply :) well and if i try with another app store, will they do the same thing? which would be the best? I sent an email to them, through the developer panel, I'll put the answer here, it might help someone.